# AngularJS - Controller attachments to modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just getting to grips with angularJS.  I notice there are several ways to create a controller, one method where you just declare a js function, and one where you create a controller off a module?

What is the key difference?

i.e

```
function GreetingController($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}
```

Versus

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Using the first method can you reuse the controller across modules with separate scopes?

Many thanks

Regards

I

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Although Angular allows you to create Controller functions in the
>   global scope, this is not recommended.

The key difference is that you would never use the first one ;) As for reuse: You could combine both approaches:

```
function GreetingController($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', GreetingController]);
```

Comment: Thanks, so you are still creating a controller with global scope? Why is the first such bad mojo? Trying to understand the difference, or is it just reuse?

Comment: @user1754307 Not exactly. Essentially it's the second approach with the function declaration pulled out. That makes it reusable. The first starts being a mess as soon as you minify your code. It won't work anymore. That's not an issue with the combined solution.